# docker-compose: Cannot find module 'typeorm'

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

This may be a duplicate question but I'm not able to figure out. I'm trying to dockerize following:

```
Postgres + NodeJs(Express, server) + Angular (dashboard)
```

Both the projects on build produces files in **/dist** folder

I can build and run the projects individually

My directory structure:

```
/root
   docker-compose.yml
   dashboard
   server
```

Here are docker files for server and frontend projects:

**dashboard/Dockerfile**

```
# Stage 1 - Build project
FROM node:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app

# Whatever directory you can use
COPY . /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

# Stage 2 - Deploy in nginx
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

**server/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /app

# Adding package.json first
# If the package.json file changes, then Docker will re-run the npm install sequence otherwise Docker will use our cache and skip that part.
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

# Copy source code to docker image
COPY ./dist/* /app/
COPY .env.docker /app/.env

EXPOSE 3000
CMD node server.js
```

**docker-compose**

```
# Specify docker compose version
version: "3.7"

# Specify all the services we want in the container
services:
 db:
  # Type of database
  image: postgres

  # Pass values to database
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: 'somedb'
    POSTGRES_USER: 'someuser'
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'somepassword'
  volumes:
    # Map path of data directory of postgres to local one
    - ./pgdata:/varlib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - '5432:5432'

 # node server
 server:
   build: server
   links:
    - db
   ports:
    - '3000:3000'
   volumes:
    - ./server/dist:/app

 # front end
 dashboard:
   build: dashboard
   depends_on:
    - server
   ports:
    - '80:80'
   volumes:
    - ./dashboard/angular/dist:/app
```

I tried following commands by looking at different suggestions:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

OR

```
docker-compose up --build
```

In both cases, I'm getting following error:

```
db_1            | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1            | This user must also own the server process.
db_1            | 
server_1     | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834
server_1     |   throw err;
server_1     |   ^
server_1     | 
server_1     | Error: Cannot find module 'typeorm'
server_1     | Require stack:
server_1     | - /app/server.js
server_1     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:15)
server_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
server_1     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
server_1     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
server_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:15:19)
server_1     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
server_1     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
server_1     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
server_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
server_1     |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
server_1     |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
server_1     |   requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
server_1     | }
db_1            | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1            | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1            | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
```

When I build server individually, I don't get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Any more information required?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include **typeorm** in your **package.json** file and also, run `docker-compose build` before you run your server using `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Solved adding "typeorm" explicit dependency in packages.json. Like:

```
  "dependencies": {
        "typeorm": "^0.2.29"
        ...
  }
```